# Converting List to Float from Json in Python

Tags: python, json, list, pandas

I have a problem, i want to converting my list from my json file. When i'm trying to convert smaller file with the same format, the result is good as i expected. But when i change the data with bigger file and same format, I get an error like this:

could not convert string to float: '-2.942-2.942', but after i checked i dont have a string '-2.942-2.942' in my bigger json file. So my question is: Is it an issue with my RAM memory so my computer can't convert the list to float?

I have this JSON data:

```
    {
    "En": -2.942,
    "atoms": [
        {
            "type": "Br",
            "xyz": [
                -4.0223,
                0.5054,
                -0.022
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Cl",
            "xyz": [
                3.9221,
                0.4837,
                0.009
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "N",
            "xyz": [
                0.0218,
                -0.5066,
                -0.0031
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "C",
            "xyz": [
                -1.1862,
                0.3061,
                0.0071
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "C",
            "xyz": [
                1.2137,
                0.3338,
                0.0107
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "C",
            "xyz": [
                -2.4113,
                -0.5886,
                0.0255
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "C",
            "xyz": [
                2.4622,
                -0.5338,
                -0.0271
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                -1.2118,
                0.9549,
                -0.8777
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                -1.1963,
                0.9561,
                0.8911
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                1.2242,
                0.9489,
                0.9188
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                1.2105,
                1.0092,
                -0.854
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                0.0291,
                -1.1038,
                -0.8296
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                -2.46,
                -1.2431,
                -0.8498
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                -2.4697,
                -1.1924,
                0.9358
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                2.5076,
                -1.2058,
                0.8359
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "H",
            "xyz": [
                2.5034,
                -1.1368,
                -0.9398
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": 16164,
    "shapeM": [
        146.89,
        7.96,
        0.86,
        0.63,
        0.1,
        0.01,
        0.0,
        1.5,
        0.03,
        0.07,
        0.0,
        0.06,
        0.02,
        0.02
    ]
}
```

And this is my python script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('testdata.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

grouper = itemgetter("En")
total = 0
quantity = 0
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(data, key = grouper),grouper):
    total = float(''.join(map(str, [item["En"] for item in grp]))) #converting list to str to float
    quantity += 1
average = total/quantity
print(average,total,quantity)
```

Comment: `total = float(''.join(map(str,...` is suspicious.

Comment: I don't even know what the comment "converting list to str to float" was supposed to mean, but what @jedwards quoted is almost certainly the source of the error. `-2.942-2.942` would be the result of concatenation of the two `En` values, which certainly isn't floatable.

Comment: @Amadan i'm try to change the value of "En: -2.942 " to 0 and then i run my python code and now the error is changing to  -1.8038-1.8038. But when i separated this data into small part my code is working. Do i have a problem with the memory? I'm not sure the problem is json data

Comment: @jedwards yes looking suspicious. but when i change my json data into small file contain the error "En", my python code is working well. So what is the problem? I really confused with this problem.

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive yes, i have the data with "En: -2.942". But when i try to make a smaller json data contains this "En: -2.942" data. My code is working well. Do you know what is the problem? Thx

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive i already understand the problem. My code can't convert the string between (-2.942, 2.942) to float. So why this problem can be happen?

Comment: @jedwards i already understand the problem. My code can't convert the string between (-2.942, 2.942) to float. So why this problem can be happen?

Comment: @Amadan  i already understand the problem. My code can't convert the string between (-2.942, 2.942) to float. So why this problem can be happen?